# Flattening a Binary Tree, return branches as Lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to break a binary tree apart, and return a list of all the branches as lists. The issue is removing older elements from the list so that I don't end up with nodes from other branches.

I've done the problem recursively, but translating the same logic into iteration is what is really making it difficult for me. I've tried using something like flags by pushing on nodes to denote when all leaves have been used, and an second data structure to store how many children each node has but it hasn't yielded much.

EDIT2:

I realize now that originally I had posted the question with only the broken iterative version, and a pretty poor explanation for poor solution.

My current code for this problem is as follows. The two main questions I have now are: 1) Would it be possible to do it without the auxiliary stack that keeps track of children, and 2) if I am understanding it right, the runtime is O(N) and space is O(logN), is this correct? Thank you very much.

(Main confusion being that the for the final branch, the innermost while loop has to iterate O(logN) times as it follows the auxiliary stack up the rightmost branch.)

```
class TreeNode
{
    int value;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int value) { this.value = value; }
}

    public List<List<Integer>> Solution(TreeNode root)
    {
        if (root == null) { return null; }

        List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack();
        Stack<Integer> aux = new Stack();
        stack.push(root);

        while (!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            int child = 0;
            TreeNode node = stack.pop();
            temp.add(node.value);
            if (node.right != null) {
                stack.push(node.right);
                child++;
            }
            if (node.left != null) {
                stack.push(node.left);
                child++;
            }
            aux.push(child);
            if ((node.left == null) && (node.right == null)) {
                ret.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp));
                while ((!aux.isEmpty()) && (aux.peek() - 1) <= 0)
                {
                    temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
                    aux.pop();
                }
                if (!aux.isEmpty()) { aux.push(aux.pop() - 1); }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: your problem is within your task definition : what is "only branches" supposed to mean? Only Nodes with children? Only Children? Both? Why? If "Only Children" : what makes you think a node cannot be child and parent at the same time? At which level are nodes **actual** children? The very last one? The first one? How does one of the "other" branches look like? Which ones are not "other"? It seems to me that you dont actually want to **flatten** the tree but instead **select specific nodes** ... at least thats what your recursive algorithm does in a rather weird way

Comment: Sorry I did a rather poor job of explaining what I wanted the program to do. Also the formatting of the tree was really bad, I apologize. I've edited it a bit better to represent what it should do.